# Is there a known problem with HERE map tiles api in the last few days?

Tags: api, dictionary, here-api

we are receiving errors from the HERE map tiles rest API, but the error is only when trying to get the map tiles with a computer located in Florida. From a computer located in Israel, everything is fine.
Any known issue?

See below -

```
"_priority": "High",
        "_resourceType": "image",
        "cache": {},
        "pageref": "page_1",
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://3.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/15/9050/13824/256/png8?app_id=XXX=eng",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": ":method",
              "value": "GET"
            },
            {
              "name": ":authority",
              "value": "3.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com"
            },
            {
              "name": ":scheme",
              "value": "https"
            },
            {
              "name": ":path",
              "value": "/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/15/9050/13824/256/png8?app_id=XXX=eng"
            },
            {
              "name": "user-agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept",
              "value": "image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-site",
              "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-mode",
              "value": "no-cors"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-dest",
              "value": "image"
            },
            {
              "name": "referer",
              "value": "https://eu.percepto.co/"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "app_id",
              "value": "XXX"
            },
            {
              "name": "app_code",
              "value": "XXX"
            },
            {
              "name": "lg",
              "value": "eng"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 0,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "x-unknown"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 0,
          "_error": "net::ERR_ABORTED"
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "",
        "startedDateTime": "2020-11-30T18:10:30.325Z",
        "time": 1.3352910000830889,
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 1.3352910000830889,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 0,
          "receive": 0,
          "_blocked_queueing": -1
        }
      },
```

Comment: There was sever down when your request running. please have below answer about the Server status. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes HERE services are down in some region and you can see the status of the services at this link:
[HERE System Status](https://status.here.com/status)